# Problem with calling functions with tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

```
from tkinter import *
from random import *


root = Tk()

#A function to create the turn for the current player. The current player isnt in this code as it is not important
def turn():
    window = Tk()  
    dice = Button(window, text="Roll the dice!", bg= "white", command=lambda:diceAction(window))
    dice.pack()
    window.mainloop()

#a function to simulate a dice. It kills the function turn.
def diceAction(window):
    result = Tk()
    y = randint(1, 6)
    quitButton = Button(result, text="Ok!", bg="white", command=result.destroy)
    quitButton.pack()
    window.destroy()
    result.mainloop()


#A function to create the playing field and to start the game
def main():
    label1 = Button(root, text="hi", bg="black")

    label1.pack()


    while 1:
        turn()
        print("Hi")
        turn()


main()

root.mainloop()
```

My problem is that the code in the while function after the first turn() the code isnt executed until i close the root window(which i dont want because it represents the playing field). You can copy this code and execute it yourself if you want.

I have no idea what causes this and havent found anything online. Sorry for the long code but i wrote it so that it is executeable.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why this particular problem is occurring, but there are a couple of things in your code that are considered bad practice.
Instead of creating multiple instances of Tk(), you should use Toplevel widgets for any pop-up windows needed. Also, it's better to use root.mainloop() to run the program rather than a while loop.

I've made some edits to your code so that it uses a Toplevel widget and discards of the while loop.

```
from tkinter import *
from random import *


#A function to create the turn for the current player. The current player isnt in this code as it is not important
def turn(prev=None):
    # destroy the previous turn
    if prev:
        prev.destroy()

    # pop up with dice
    window = Toplevel()  
    dice = Button(window, text="Roll the dice!", bg= "white")
    dice.config(command=lambda b=dice, w=window:diceAction(b, w))
    dice.pack()


#a function to simulate a dice, reconfigures the pop-up
def diceAction(button, window):
    # roll dice
    y = randint(1, 6)
    # use dice result here?
    print(y)

    # reconfigure button, the command now starts a new turn
    button.config(text='ok', command=lambda w=window:turn(prev=w))




root = Tk()

# I hijacked this button to use as a start button
label1 = Button(root, text="hi", bg="black", command=turn)
label1.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

I don't know if this is what you need, but it functions as the code in the question would if it worked.
Sorry I couldn't help with the cause of the error.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Is it possible to automatically start the turn process without the need to press a button?

Comment: Yes, if you call the turn function just before you start mainloop.

Comment: Unfortunatly it doesnt quite work. The reason i call turn() in the code 2 times, is because i give it the parameter player1/player2(which is currentPlayer in the function). With this method it would always use the same player :/

Comment: Hey it kinda works now but i have a different problem:   I call turn() 2 times in while ith player1 and player2. The problem is that the 2nd turn() doesnt "wait" for the first one to finish(aka for me the button to press). I want them to pop up after each other, do you have any idea how to implement this?

Comment: You could just call turn once, and then have a parameter that you swapped each time for player 1/2

Comment: I solved it! If you use window.quit and window.destroy it will pass the mainloop and close the window. Thanks anyways